# Javascript infinite recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, google-apps-script

I have the following `tags` array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "tagName": "Optimizely Setup",
    "children": [],
  },
  {
    "tagName": "Adobe DTM Bootstrap",
    "children": [
      {
        "tagName": "Adobe Analytics",
        "children": [
          {
            "tagName": "Adobe Analytics",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "tagName": "Google Content Experiments",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "tagName": "Google Tag Manager",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "tagName": null,
    "children": [
      {
        "tagName": "Wordpress Stats",
        "children": [],

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "tagName": "AddThis Widget",
    "children": [
      {
        "tagName": "AddThis",
        "children": [],
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My goal is to check the `tagName` from each object. As you can see, any object can have nested `children` arrays of objects that need to be checked by `tagName`.

I'm trying to use a recursive function for this, but I'm stuck on an infinite loop...

```
  var tagNameArr = [];
  var findObjectByLabel = function(obj) {
    for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      if(obj[i].tagName != null){
        var tms = obj[i].tagName.match(/Adobe DTM Bootstrap|Google Tag Manager/g)
        if(tms === null) {
          tagNameArr.push(obj[i].tagName)
          if(obj[i].children.length > 0) {
            findObjectByLabel(obj[i].children)
          }

        }

      }

    }
    return null;
  }
  findObjectByLabel(tags);
```

This is my first time using recursion and any solutions would help a lot

---

Bug found: the `for` loop is missing the variable initialization

Comment: That's a little odd, the code should terminate (unless you have a cyclical object, ie. `var a = {}; a.children = a;`) Can you try adding `console.log(obj);` to the start of the function, to see what it's trying to do?

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out why it isn't stopping.

Comment: [Code seems to work ok](https://jsfiddle.net/tsLofk49/)

Comment: The loop gets restarted when it calls `findObjectByLabel(obj[i].children)`

Comment: @Valip nope, because `i` is a local variable.

Comment: Hmmm...maybe this is a `google apps script` bug

Comment: can you show the error message you are getting?

Comment: Found the bug...in my code I missed to add `var` before `i`  in the for loop...

Comment: Is not getting an infinity loop for me...

Comment: Having the `var` there makes it a local variable, otherwise it assumes a global.  So yep, that'd do it.

Comment: wow, I really didn't see this when scanning the code. Tricksy Javascripsie